# CORS issue vue/express/axios

Tags: express, heroku, axios, cors

I have a VueJS app consuming an ExpressJS api. Attempting to hit an express route from the front end landing page form to send a "Contact Us" email via SendGrid but getting a proxy error in production on heroku.

here is the method in my component:

```
 async sendContactMessage() {
      console.log('email valid? ', this.validateEmail(this.contactEmail))
      if (!this.validateEmail(this.contactEmail)) {
        this.contactNotice = "Please enter a valid email."
      }
      
      else if (this.contactMessage.length < 10) {
        this.contactNotice = " The message is too short"
      } else {
        await MailersService.sendMessage({
          email: this.contactEmail,
          message: this.contactMessage
        })
        this.showContact = false
      }
    },
```

here is the api call in MailersService:

```
sendMessage (params) {
    let response = axios.post('/contacts/question', params)
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.data;
    }
  }
```

on the Express side, here is the route I am posting to:

```
router.post('/question', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('in Express, sending mail from contact form. this is request: ', req)
  let newMessage = req.body
  console.log("new message object is: ", newMessage)
  const msg = {
    to: 'contact@companydomain.com',
    from: req.body.email, // Use the email address or domain you verified above
    subject: 'Message from Beta Signup Form',
    text: req.body.message
  };
  await sgMail.send(msg);

  res.json({
    success: true, message: 'ok' 
  });   // respond back to request
});
```

in app.js for cors, I have:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use( function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
})
```

This works locally, but on Heroku, it throws the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...-api.herokuapp.com/api/contacts/question' from origin 'https://....com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Do you handle the `OPTIONS` call? It sounds like you are not handling that, which causes it to never do the actual call.

Comment: Hrmmm; nvm. That is what `app.use(cors());` is supposed to do I guess. Weird.

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight, and try adding `app.options('*', cors())`.

Comment: Tried this with no luck. Error seems to indicate this is something that needs to be provided from the client side right?